# Mapping a bidirectional One-to-Many Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-jdbc

I am trying to map a bi-directional (one to many and many to one) relationship in Hibernate. We're getting errors when attempting save a result.

The error we're getting is:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.example.Component.resultId
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:92)

From the source code below a `Result` can have many `Component`s and many `Component`s can belong to a single `Result`. One of the requirement is that the `resultId` in `Result` **must** be a `String`. This requirement is out of our control.

An example Entity source code is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Result extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resultId")
    private List<Component> component = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cmpt")
@XmlRootElement
public class Component extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Result.class)
    private String resultId;
}
```

---

**Here is the solution that worked for me**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Result extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, nullable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resultId")
    private List<Component> component = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cmpt")
@XmlRootElement
public class Component extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name = "result_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String resultId;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the ID field in the entities? The `@JoinColumn` annotation on `@OneToMany` is useless, and the `@ManyToOne` annotation on a field of type String is useless, as well, because you can use this annotation only on entities.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to create a bidirectional entity is this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Result extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy="result")
    private List<Component> component = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cmpt")
@XmlRootElement
public class Component extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Result.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "result_id")  //result_id is the column name (foreign key) in cmpt table
    private Result result;

    @Column(name = "result_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String resultId;
}
```

This will ensure there will be only one bi-direction relation (not two uni-directional relations etc). Let me know if you are expecting something else.

Update 1:

You can add another key to the entity as specified above. You'll get the foreign key as a string. But you need to remember that the actual mapping with JoinColumn should not be removed. I have tested the above configuration and it seems to work for me.

Comment: The `resultId` in `Component ` **must** be a `String`

Comment: You can access the resultId from result.getId() no?

Comment: I understand your solution but It's a constraint that is out of our control. The `resultId` in `Component ` **must** be a `String`

Comment: Thanks got it to work - Your solution was very helpful. I've updated the question with my solution that has worked for me.

Comment: If it has worked for you, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: I have to wait two days to accept my own answer. Will do that in two days time

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an entity as the field annotated with @ManyToOne. Also i think in your case you should put the @Join column on the Component side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cmpt")
@XmlRootElement
public class Component extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "resultId")
    private Result result;
}
```

now you dont need the `targetEntity` attrbute.

Also remove the `@JoinColumn` from `@OneToMany` and add `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Result extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy="result")
    private List<Component> component = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution but It's a constraint that is out of our control. The `resultId` in `Component ` **must** be a `String`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the annotation `@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Result.class)` from **Component.java** class and when you tries to save data first you have to save **Result** using save method and then you got the **resultId** returned by save method set this **resultId** in component entity using setter and getter and then save the **component**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Result extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, nullable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resultId")
    private List<Component> component = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cmpt")
@XmlRootElement
public class Component extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name = "result_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String resultId;
}
```